# Multi Level Bash Completion

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I currently have a Bash completion file which completes a single parameter from a list of allowed commands for a script called `pbt`. This is the working Bash completion file:

```bash
_pbt_complete()
{
    local cur goals

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    goals='asadmin clean deploy'
    cur=`echo $cur`
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${goals}" ${cur}))
}

complete -F _pbt_complete pbt
```

So if I call

```
pbt <tab>
```

Bash completes to all allowed commands (`asadmin`, `clean`, `deploy`), which is okay. **Now I want to add a *second level* to the completion.** So for example if I type

```
pbt asadmin <tab>
```

I want it to complete only options that are available inside the `asadmin` "environment" (which I'll also define inside the Bash completion file). For example `pbt asadmin [start-domain|stop-domain]`. But if I type

```
pbt deploy <tab>
```

It should complete to another set of options. For example, `pbt deploy [all|current]`. So the options for the second command should always depend on the first command.

How can I do that in the completion file?

Comment: Have you installed or looked at the bash-completion package? http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/ The p4 and apt modules do this.

Comment: Both this link and the "p4 example" link below are broken. I believe this is the same package. It was listed on the Debian Bullseye page for bash-completion package: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion .. also check my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Thanks to [mkb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5302650/241211#comment5979992_5302650), I looked into [the `p4` example](http://fts.ifac.cnr.it/cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/doc/bash/completion-contrib/p4), which was—unlike the Git example—simple enough for me to adapt to my case. Here is the working version which does exactly what I asked for:

```bash
have pbt &&
_pbt_complete()
{
  local cur prev

  COMPREPLY=()
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

  if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "asadmin deploy" -- $cur) )
  elif [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 2 ]; then
    case "$prev" in
      "asadmin")
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "start-domain stop-domain" -- $cur) )
        ;;
      "deploy")
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "all current" -- $cur) )
        ;;
      *)
        ;;
    esac
  fi

  return 0
} &&
complete -F _pbt_complete pbt
```

Comment: I am totally lost after looking into the git example also, this one looks very good!

Comment: bummer the "p4 example" link is broken. I think I found the original source in my answer. Also, there is a way to not have to build every double or triple level command individually, by using the Complete command, which asks for the "previous" word, for context in the multi-level command tree.

Comment: As it is one of the first answer on Google, you might want to use `mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(compgen -W "${command_args}" -- "${cur}")` instead of `COMPREPLY=( ... )` as recommanded by ShellCheck [SC2207](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2207).

Answer (score 2):

Btw, here are two useful tips on better tab completion:

- use `bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'` # this makes only one Tab necessary to show possible completions
- use this Fish-like package for Bash that automatically shows possibles and history as you type: https://superuser.com/a/1644033/388883 (called ble.sh)

---

Here is more [info](https://askubuntu.com/a/1444201/795299) on how to use the `complete` command to adjust tab completetion. This page has an incredible breakdown, and discusses known application using "cobra (Golang), click (Python) and clap (Rust) tools"
https://echorand.me/posts/linux_shell_autocompletion/ (and how Git uses Compgen)

---

Here is a link the the GH repo for Debian `bash-completion`: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion

Q. What is the search order for the completion file of each target command?

A. The completion files of commands are looked up by the shell function __load_completion. Here, the search order in bash-completion >= 2.12 is explained.

- BASH_COMPLETION_USER_DIR. The subdirectory completions of each paths in BASH_COMPLETION_USER_DIR separated by colons is considered for a completion directory.
- The location of the main bash_completion file. The subdirectory completions in the same directory as bash_completion is considered.
- The location of the target command. When the real location of the command is in the directory /bin or /sbin, the directory /share/bash-completion/completions is considered.
- XDG_DATA_DIRS (or the system directories /usr/local/share:/usr/share if empty). The subdirectory bash-completion/completions of each paths in XDG_DATA_DIRS separated by colons is considered.

The completion files of the name  or .bash, where  is the name of the target command, are searched in the above completion directories in order. The file that is found first is used. When no completion file is found in any completion directories in this process, the completion files of the name _ is next searched in the completion directories in order.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at how the completion for git is done, as an example. (This takes 2257 lines of function definitions and additional 14 variables in my bash setup.)