# Enable bash tab completion for Mercurial (hg)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, mercurial, tab-completion

I've installed Mercurial (1.4.3-1) on ubuntu and it doesn't do tab completion in bash by default. What is the simplest way to enable this feature?

Comment: You should really consider using a newer Mercurial release.  There are PPA repositories available for Ubuntu that you can enable to get your normal auto-update behavior of Mercurial in a seamless fashion that won't have you more than a year behind current: https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases

Answer (score 12):

You need to

- Install an up-to-date package for Mercurial, see the [Mercurial PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases). This will give you a `/etc/bash_completion.d/mercurial` file with the completion code for Mercurial. You can source this file directly to enable completion support for Mercurial.

You can also enable completion support for all programs:

- Install the `bash-completion` package: `aptitude install bash-completion`.
- Source `/etc/bash_completion` in your `~/.bashrc`  file:

  ```
  # Use bash-completion, if available
  if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
  ```

  This will enable completion for all commands, including Mercurial.

Answer (score 5):

```
curl https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/raw-file/tip/contrib/bash_completion -o ~/.hg-completion.bash && source ~/.hg-completion.bash
```

---

The mercurial autocomplete script appears to be maintained here:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/tip/contrib/bash_completion

`source` this script in your `.bashrc` or equivalent

Answer (score 2):

## System wide

for all users.

```
$ sudo curl https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/raw-file/tip/contrib/bash_completion -o /etc/bash_completion.d/mercurial
$ source /etc/bash_completion.d/mercurial
```

Answer (score 1):

The bash_completion script location has changed so you need to do

```
curl https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/raw-file/tip/contrib/bash_completion -o ~/.hg-completion.bash && source ~/.hg-completion.bash
```

instead of

```
curl http://www.selenic.com/hg/raw-file/tip/contrib/bash_completion -o ~/.hg-completion.bash && source ~/.hg-completion.bash
```

Comment: This answer is cross-platform and doesn't need Ubuntu. I used it on OS X. It should work everywhere you have `bash`, `curl` (and `hg` ;-).

Comment: Worked for me on OSX. Thank you!

Comment: You should update this to include adding `source ~/.hg-completion.bash` in your `.bashrc` so that you don't have to run this in every new shell.

Answer (score 0):

Install `bash-completion` package in your Linux (depends on Linux Distribution you are using).

Then go to `/etc/bash_completion.d/` and create a file called `hg`
and put the content of this script (below) into created `hg` file.

http://fts.ifac.cnr.it/cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/doc/bash/completion-contrib/hg

Comment: Unfortunately the link above doesn't seem to work anymore - results in a 403.

Comment: I think this is the new location for `bash-completion` (at least according to the Debian Bullseye repo): https://github.com/scop/bash-completion .. heres some more info on it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74662464/4240654

Answer (score 0):

Since it's neither tagged nor titled "ubuntu", and because googling with fedora also leads here, I'll add a variation on Martin's answer that works by referencing `/etc/bash_completion.d/mercurial.sh`instead of `/etc/bash_completion` in your `~/.bashrc`:

`# Use bash-completion, if available
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion.d/mercurial.sh ]; then
  . /etc/bash_completion.d/mercurial.sh
fi`

Not sure if the OS makes this distinction necessary, but this works for me on Fedora 11 through 20.

**Correction:**  Fedora 11 and Fedora 20.  (Not tested 12-19.)